# Вопрос по Java - cамо прерывается воспроизведение mp3-файла в MediaPlayer на JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, mediaplayer, mp3

При запуске приложения JavaFX у меня начинает проигрываться фоновая музыка MP3 и через 2-3 секунды сама затыкается. Время разное и даже может проиграть до конца. Пробовал другой mp3, то же самое. Я бигиннер в Java и прошу помочь, т.к. ничего не смог нагуглить. Вот мой код:

```
package com.example.javafxproject1;

import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import java.io.File;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 800, 450);
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX-приложение");
      
        String musicFile = "access/background.mp3";

        Media sound = new Media(new File(musicFile).toURI().toString());
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);

        mediaPlayer.play();

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch();

    }
}
```

Comment: Если вы тестируете на эмуляторе, тогда это нормально, это глюк эмулятора а не приложения.

Comment: Спасибо, верно, запускаю в среде IntelliJ IDEA. Может это как-то фиксится для ИДЕИ? Как можно запустить, чтобы не глючило? Пробовал перевести в exe программкой Launch4j, но не получается, т.к. версию JDK я использую 11, в ней JRE 1.8 и launch4j при сборке ругается что у меня версия класса 55, а JRE поддерживает только версию 52 макс. Видел ответы на подобный трабл здесь на форуме, но решения нет в этих ответах.

Comment: В других (сторонних) плеерах файлы, которые не прогривыются полность, без проблем воспроизводятся?

Comment: Проблема была в коде, инициализация плеера была внутри метода, как только я вынес инициализацию в область данных класса, а в методе оставил только play(), все заработало без прерываний. Какой-то трабл с событием клика...